# Shared process service via svchost.exe in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I've been looking into writing a service that runs under the context of a shared `svchost.exe` process, mainly for curiosity. I've found a [couple of](http://forum.sysinternals.com/writing-a-service-that-runs-under-svchost_topic11974.html) [resources](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314056) related to the subject, but nothing about .NET services. I know how to write standard Windows services, but is is possible to host a .NET windows service under `svchost`, and if so, how is it done?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849613/can-i-use-svchost-exe-to-host-my-own-services). My guess is that it is expecting a standard exported symbol to know what to call. If that is the case it certainly won't work for C# (or any other managed language).

Comment: One thing you can try would be to use `dumpbin` with a couple of the standard DLLs that are hosted by `svchost` and figure out which ones are common (likely indicating the necessary API), then write a C++/CLI project exposing exports that match (KIM this is a guess since I _don't_ use managed C++) and invoke your purely managed methods based on what is passed in...

Comment: Interesting. I wonder how the OS handles loading .NET code into native processes. I can imagine I'd get an `ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION` exception from the CPU...

Comment: Be aware that, to the best of my knowledge, running third-party services in svchost.exe isn't supported.

Comment: Polynomial - @Harry is correct of course, but if you're doing this strictly for the purpose of research (with **no** intention of publishing anything production from it), don't let that deter you.

Comment: I'm aware that it's not supported and may break in future. I'm playing with it out of curiosity, more than anything.